# Log experiments with MLflow to DAGsHub tracking server

Tags: mlflow

I'm trying to use MLflow and log my experiments to DAGsHub's remote-tracking server but I get this error message:

`WARNING mlflow.utils.autologging_utils: Encountered unexpected error during tensorflow autologging: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'`  with a lot of HTML text.

When I check my DAGsHub repo, no new experiment is created.

What am I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please paste what is in the HTML... Most probably there are authentication problems or something like